# Reading Content from File in J2ME

Tags: java, file-io, java-me, midp, file-connection

I am trying to read the content of a file but it seems not to work. I surfed the net and found different implementations as shown(read(), read2(), readLine()) but each time a run the codes they all give a NullPointer exception. Please what can I do to rectify this problem.

```
     private String folder;
        static String filename;
        //IMPLEMENTATION 1
        private void readFile(String f) {
            try {
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(f));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = readLine(reader)) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
/**
         * Reads a single line using the specified reader.
         * @throws java.io.IOException if an exception occurs when reading the
         * line
         */
        private String readLine(InputStreamReader reader) throws IOException {
            // Test whether the end of file has been reached. If so, return null.
            int readChar = reader.read();
            if (readChar == -1) {
                return null;
            }
            StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer("");
            // Read until end of file or new line
            while (readChar != -1 && readChar != '\n') {
                if (readChar != '\r') {
                    string.append((char) readChar);
                }
                // Read the next character
                readChar = reader.read();
            }
            return string.toString();
        }

        //IMPLEMENTATION 2
        private String read(String file) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int chars, i = 0;
            while ((chars = is.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) chars);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        //IMPLEMENTATION 3
        private String read2(String file) throws IOException {
            String content = "";
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(file));
            StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer(1024);
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                temp.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            content = temp.toString();
                    return content;
        }

        public void execute() throws IOException {
            folder = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos") + "mcast/";
            String path = folder + filename + ".txt";
            FileConnection c = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path, Connector.READ_WRITE);

            try {
                // Checking if the directoy exists or not. If it doesn't exist we create it.
                if (c.exists()) {
            readFile(path);
                    //read(path);
                   // read2(path);
                    System.out.println(read(path));
                } else {
                    System.out.println(filename + ".txt does not exist. Please specify a correct file name");
                }
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }
        }

private String readLine(InputStreamReader reader) throws IOException {
        // Test whether the end of file has been reached. If so, return null.
        int readChar = reader.read();
        if (readChar == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer("");
        // Read until end of file or new line
        while (readChar != -1 && readChar != '\n') {
            // Append the read character to the string. Some operating systems
            // such as Microsoft Windows prepend newline character ('\n') with
            // carriage return ('\r'). This is part of the newline character
            // and therefore an exception that should not be appended to the
            // string.
            if (readChar != '\r') {
                string.append((char) readChar);
            }
            // Read the next character
            readChar = reader.read();
        }
        return string.toString();
    }


    }
```

Comment: Where you getting `NullPointerException`? Have you debug your application?

Comment: Yes. I was getthing it in  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(f));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ISSUE:** *Referring to file using incorrect method*

[getResourceAsStream(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is for loading resources from the classpath either from your binary package (.jar) or the classpath directory.

So what it essentially means is, to **read a file from the binary package use getClass().getResourceAsStream()** and to **read a file from the device's physical memory use FileConnection API's.**

You are trying to create the inputstream from the file schema of the type used in FileConnection hence it will not work. So to solve your problem you have replace the inputstream object initialization in the `read(...)`, `read2(...)` and `readFile(...)` with below code

`InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);`      *//here `in` is the method's input parameter of type InputStream*

and in `execute(...)` pass the file connection inputstream as below

`readFile(c.openInputStream());`           *//here `c` is object of type FileConnection*

.

*You might also want to consider these if you are testing your application in emulator / device*

1. Make sure the `System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos")` returns
   **NON NULL** value
2. The file is stored at appropriate location in the system

Comment: Not yet. I understand the reason you gave but I dont understand how to implement exactly what you explained.

Comment: I will appreciate it if you could make the desired changes. I'll edit the original code above to include the readLine method which I omitted.

Comment: Please do inform me if the changes are made. Thanks alot.

Comment: Just Solved it. Its Working now. Thanks alot. U are my Hero. lol